# oracle Query to find the maximum relation

Tags: oracle

I have a question in oracle

```
SELECT q2.Director_ID, q2.Actor_ID
   FROM (SELECT MAX(n.Num_Joint_Movies) AS Max_Joint_Movies
      FROM (SELECT d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) AS Num_Joint_Movies
              FROM Movies_Directors AS d
              , Roles AS a
                where d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
             GROUP BY d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
           ) AS n
   ) AS q3,
(SELECT d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) AS Num_Joint_Movies
      FROM Movies_Directors AS d
     , Roles AS a
       where d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
     GROUP BY d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
    ) AS q2
where q3.Max_Joint_Movies = q2.Num_Joint_Movies
```

but I am getting the error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Could you please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: fiddle please - give us fiddle link

Comment: can anybody suggest a better way to write this query...

Answer (score 1):

your SQL is failing as you've used the AS keyword on the table joins.

ie you should have had:

```
SELECT q2.Director_ID, q2.Actor_ID
   FROM (SELECT MAX(n.Num_Joint_Movies) AS Max_Joint_Movies
      FROM (SELECT d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) AS Num_Joint_Movies
              FROM Movies_Directors  d
              , Roles  a
                where d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
             GROUP BY d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
           ) n
   )  q3,
(SELECT d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) AS Num_Joint_Movies
      FROM Movies_Directors  d
     , Roles  a
       where d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
     GROUP BY d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
    )  q2
where q3.Max_Joint_Movies = q2.Num_Joint_Movies;
```

your SQL can be simplified to this though:

```
select Director_ID, Actor_ID, Num_Joint_Movies
  from (select d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) Num_Joint_Movies,
               rank() over (order by count(*) desc) r
                  from Movies_Directors  d
                       inner join Roles  a
                               on d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
                 group by d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID)
 where r = 1;
```

edit a small sample:

```
SQL> create table Movies_Directors(director_id, Movie_ID)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 1 from dual
  4  union all
  5  select 1, 2 from dual
  6  union all
  7  select 2, 3 from dual
  8  union all
  9  select 2, 4 from dual
 10  union all
 11  select 3, 1 from dual ;

Table created.

SQL> create table roles(movie_id, actor_Id)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 1 from dual union all
  4  select 1, 2 from dual union all
  5  select 1, 3 from dual union all
  6  select 1, 4 from dual union all
  7  select 2, 1 from dual union all
  8  select 2, 3 from dual union all
  9  select 3, 3 from dual union all
 10  select 3, 1 from dual;

Table created.
```

if we add a rank analytic:
    SQL> select d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) Num_Joint_Movies,
      2                 rank() over (order by count(*) desc) r
      3                               from Movies_Directors  d
      4                                    inner join Roles  a
      5                                            on d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
      6                              group by d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
      7  /

```
DIRECTOR_ID   ACTOR_ID NUM_JOINT_MOVIES          R
----------- ---------- ---------------- ----------
          1          1                2          1
          1          3                2          1
          2          3                1          3
          1          2                1          3
          3          2                1          3
          3          3                1          3
          3          4                1          3
          2          1                1          3
          1          4                1          3
          3          1                1          3

10 rows selected.
```

now just filter on rank 1..

```
SQL> select Director_ID, Actor_ID, Num_Joint_Movies
  2    from (select d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) Num_Joint_Movies,
  3                 rank() over (order by count(*) desc) r
  4                               from Movies_Directors  d
  5                                    inner join Roles  a
  6                                            on d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
  7                              group by d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID)
  8   where r = 1;

DIRECTOR_ID   ACTOR_ID NUM_JOINT_MOVIES
----------- ---------- ----------------
          1          3                2
          1          1                2
```

vs the original (corrected) sql:
    SQL> SELECT q2.Director_ID, q2.Actor_ID
      2     FROM (SELECT MAX(n.Num_Joint_Movies) AS Max_Joint_Movies
      3        FROM (SELECT d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) AS Num_Joint_Movies
      4                FROM Movies_Directors  d
      5                , Roles  a
      6                  where d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
      7               GROUP BY d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
      8             ) n
      9     )  q3,
     10  (SELECT d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID, COUNT(*) AS Num_Joint_Movies
     11        FROM Movies_Directors  d
     12       , Roles  a
     13         where d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
     14       GROUP BY d.Director_ID, A.Actor_ID
     15      )  q2
     16  where q3.Max_Joint_Movies = q2.Num_Joint_Movies;

```
DIRECTOR_ID   ACTOR_ID
----------- ----------
          1          1
          1          3

SQL>
```

Comment: @FlorinGhita yes this works in this case (order by count(*) desc).

Comment: mmmm, nice. Some combinations don't work(probably partitioned) and I got it as rule :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Director_ID,
    Actor_ID FROM
 (SELECT
    d.Director_ID,
    a.Actor_ID,
    COUNT(*) AS Num_Joint_Movies 
FROM
    Movies_Directors AS d 
        JOIN Roles AS a 
        ON d.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID 
    GROUP BY
        d.Director_ID,
        a.Actor_ID
) WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY Num_Joint_Movies ASC
/
```

Try this one and it should work

Comment: no it dnt work it gave the same error and This query will return one row ,I want the records for all the director_id